# why I am receiving this error Attempted import error: 'history' does not contain a default export (imported as 'createBrowserHistory')

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am following a tutorial to learn routes in reactjs everything is good but I am receiving this error .

Attempted import error: 'history' does not contain a default export (imported as 'createBrowserHistory').

tutorial i am following is this https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/routing-and-navigation-in-react-cffc26e8a389

Its history.js file

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

this is app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './services/history';
import Routes from './routes';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`createBrowserHistory` is exported from `history` using `named exports`, and should be imported like this:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
```

Comment: Hi , can we declare React two times   like 
import React from 'react';
import {Switch, React} from 'react-router-dom';     AS its giving me error " Line 2:17:  Parsing error: Identifier 'React' has already been declared"

Comment: There is no named import called `React` inside `react-router-dom`

Comment: @Hamza , please have a look in this screenshot https://prnt.sc/punyw5

Comment: Just a mistake, he wanted to import `Route` and not `React`.